# ERROR While running SAP WEB IDE

Tags: web, sap, sap-hana

Failed to load component for container container. Reason: Error: "false" is of type string, expected boolean for property "visible" of Element

This error shoots up when i run my web ide

Comment: It's a common case. WebIDE is still very buggy and fails on many plugins. If it is your container/element, then you should revise its code